# Angular2 create filetree-like structure

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a filetree-like structure in Angular2. Basically I have recursive structure up to 4 levels like this:

```
Folder -Folder(empty)
       -File
       -File
       -Folder 
          -File
          -File 
          -Folder
```

and I need to show it as standard table where each File or Folder is represented as table row. So far I've tried recursive template, but it generates nested divs/tr which is really bad to style. Do you have any suggestions? Is there any way to generate from this a "standard" table with:

```
<tr>
  <td>Folder</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Folder</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>File</td>
</tr>
```

At the end is a plan to make filetree-like look with CSS.

Comment: What's the problem with generating table instead of divs? You can use `<tr myTr>` with attribute selectors (`selector: `[myTr]`), then you get a table instead of divs.

Comment: When I used recursive template with for example <tr> it generated nested <tr><tr></tr></tr> structures, what I had problems to style in desired manner.

Comment: How do you want to style the `<tr>`s to indent for deeper folder levels? I assumed you want nested tables. If you don't want I don't think you can use recursive components. You can flatten the structure and just use `*ngFor` with some indentation attribute added to each row to indicate the nesting level.